# Parámetros google maps

Tags: google-maps, url, parametros

estoy empezando a utilizar tasker y he creado una url que al decir el destino al que quiero ir, comienza la navegación desde Google maps. Mi pregunta era si existe algun parametro que al añadirlo a la url abra google maps en una esquina, en pequeñito. El codigo que tengo para que seleccione la ruta es:
`https://maps.google.com/?q=(destino)+&mode=c&avoid=toll`

Los parametros que tiene esa url son `mode=c` que es para que se inicie la ruta en coche. Y `avoid=toll` que lo utilizo para que la ruta se inicie sin peajes.
Al cambiar `(destino)` por el lugar al que quieres ir ya te lleva.
No se si me he explicado muy bien, si surge alguna duda la resolveré